# Hibernate error when loading object : java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to get my application to run hibernate with the following entity class model. I have noticed that when I load my application, I run into infinity loop. I mean because my Cart and CartItem have bidirectional relationship, and it throws an error: java.lang.StackOverflowError. I had google this issue on Hibernate Community, however, I am not sure how to fix this.Please help.

Answer from [Hibernate community](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=984479)
"I've also run into this infinite loop problem. The solution which worked in the end was:
* @IdClass
* Annotate only @Id in the "main" class
* Do your @ManyToOne in the Pk class, and make fetchType=LAZY
* Make the fetchType=LAZY in the @OneToMany"

Please see Error in details:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:506)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at com.bfd.model.Cart.toString(Cart.java:66)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at com.bfd.model.CartItem.toString(CartItem.java:20)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:507)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at com.bfd.model.Cart.toString(Cart.java:66)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at com.bfd.model.CartItem.toString(CartItem.java:20)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2854)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:458)
    at
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int userId;
    // custom id generator class
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "login_id", strategy = "com.bfd.tools.UserIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "login_id")
    @Column(name = "login_id")
    private String loginId;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20, min = 5)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]*")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-z]+([ '-][a-zA-Z]+)*")
    @Size(max = 20, min = 5)
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Size(min = 5)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^\\S+$")
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Size(max = 40, min = 10)
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "registered_date")
    private Date registerDate = new Date(
            Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
    @Column(name = "acc_balance")
    private double accountBalance = 1000;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotBlank
    @Email
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled = false;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private Cart userCart;
...getter and setter
```

Cart Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
        public class Cart implements Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "cart_id")
        private int cartId;

        @Column(name = "session_id")
        private String sessionId;

        @Column(name = "purchased")
        private Boolean purchased = false;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentCart",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<CartItem> cartItems;
... getter and setter
```

CartItem Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cartItem")
    public class CartItem implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "cartItem_id")
    private int cartItemId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="cart_id")
    private Cart parentCart;


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_id")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "purchased_quantity")
    private int purchasedQuantity;

    @Column(name = "purchased_price")
    private double purchasedPrice;
    ... getter and setter
```

Comment: The problems seems to rise within a toString()-method of one of the entities. Did you overwrite toString(). If yes, please post the methods.

Comment: Your class implements "Serializable". This means that your class can be represented by a string. This way, java gets in a loop trying to create a string for "cart->cart items-> cart parent->cart items->...". Try to test without implementing "Serializable". If it works, you need to search how to tell java to stop trying to resolve that looping. Or not implement Serializable.

Comment: Any news ? Do you fix your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is nothing to do with the Hibernate.

Without looking at the `toString()` methods in `Cart` and `CartItem` classes, you may want to check the `toString()` methods in both these classes.

I believe you are printing the `CartItem` object in the `Cart toString()` method and `Cart object` in the `CartItem toString()` method.

Answer (score 1):

usually the problem is inside circular relations. first check `equals`. it's used by hibernate and `equals` methods in different classes may call each other. so there are infinite calls and eventually they produce SO exception. second could be `toString`. if you use it in your code, mechanism will be the same. and finally check your other methods if they will always terminate even when used in complex, self-referencing graphs of objects

Comment: Thanks for your advise. i fix this issue, but it give me another error:2016-09-22 21:54:55 ERROR CustomLogger:106 - Error in Object Creation. Message: [a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.bfd.model.Product#p_00014]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.bfd.model.Product#p_00014]]

Comment: this is completely different issue. probably you need to configure id auto-generation

Answer (score 0):

Can you please delete overrided methods equals and hashcode ?